# How to get application menu over a currently running screen

Tags: android, opengl-es, google-tv

I want to get an application menu bar on the left hand side of the screen without disturbing the task that is already running for eg.a live wallpaper or video.How can it be achieved?

Comment: you want to show the menu in your application or any part of your mobile ?\

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NewPopupMenu libarary from github](https://github.com/u1aryz/Android-NewPopupMenu).

It will create instant popup menu at any location on screen on any listner.

You just have to download library and extract it, copy the source file into project,
and modify code at this line `mPopupWindow.showAtLocation(parent, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);`
and place your menu where ever you wants.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this service class. by starting this service from your activity you will get an image in your mobile screen. by adjusting that you can set any where in the mobile. and you can remove it by stopping  the service any time.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date; 
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.ViewDebug;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HUD extends Service {
    HUDView mView;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mView = new HUDView(this);
        mView.setId(R.id.button);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams paramsOrg = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,

                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);




        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(100, 100, 2007, 8, -3);
        Button bb=new Button(this);
        bb.setText("Button");
        bb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("Clicked----><<<<<<<");
            }
        });

        bb.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("Touched =----- > ");
                return false;
            }
        });

        params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.TOP;
        params.setTitle("Load Average");
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);




        wm.addView(bb, params);



    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"onDestroy", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if(mView != null)
        {
            ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).removeView(mView);
            mView = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        // Checks the orientation of the screen
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            //Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            restartService();
        } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
            //Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            restartService();
        }

    }

    private void restartService() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), HUD.class));
        startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), HUD.class));
    }
}

class HUDView extends ViewGroup {
    private Paint mLoadPaint;
    private Float XMAX=280f;
    private Float YMAX=26f;
    private int XPOS=0;     

    public HUDView(Context context) {
        super(context);


        mLoadPaint = new Paint();
        mLoadPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mLoadPaint.setTextSize(10);
        mLoadPaint.setARGB(255, 255, 0, 0);


        context.bindService(intents, aslServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);


        WindowManager wind = (WindowManager)context.getSystemService(Service.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        XPOS=wind.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        //canvas.drawText("Hello World", 5, 15, mLoadPaint);
        //canvas.drawText("Hello World", 100, 100, mLoadPaint);
        Bitmap tileImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image);

        canvas.drawBitmap(tileImage, XPOS-35, 0, null);
        XMAX=Float.parseFloat(""+(XPOS-35));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        Float x=event.getX();
        Float y=event.getY();
        System.out.println("Mview has been touched  --->  "+x +" x "+y);
        if(x > 0 && y > 0)
        {
            if(x > XMAX && y < YMAX){

                TakeMyScreen(getContext());


            }

        }



        return true;
    }




    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Must use the permission into your project manifest otherwise window has not been attach

```
android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"
```